# Why won't this work when sending an image file?

Tags: java, image, file, text, udp

Server receives a file that the client sends.
When a text file is chosen, the transfer and the writing of the file is a success, but when an image file is chosen, either the transfer or the writing of the file generates some characters not found within the original file, thus corrupting the image file. Please help :)

public class Server {

```
private DatagramSocket socket = null;
private DatagramPacket inPacket;
private DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
private byte[] inBuffer, outBuffer;
private final int port = 50000;
private ChooseDestination cf = new ChooseDestination();
private BufferedWriter bw;
private int receivedNo = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();
}

public Server(){
    this.connect();
}

public void connect(){
    try{
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        String fName = "";
        while(true){
            inPacket = null;
            // waiting for input from client
            inBuffer = new byte[1024];
            inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length);
            socket.receive(inPacket);

            // get info of client
            int source_port = inPacket.getPort();
            InetAddress source_address = inPacket.getAddress();
            System.out.println("Client: " + source_address + " Port:" + source_port);

            // converts packets received to string for content checking
            String data = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());

            if(data.contains("filename")){
                System.out.println("filename set");
                fName = cf.browseFolders() + data.substring(8);
                System.out.println("filename: " +fName);

                outBuffer = new byte[1024];
                outBuffer = ("ok").getBytes();
                outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length, source_address, source_port);
                socket.send(outPacket);
            }

            if (data.endsWith("ERROR!")) {
                System.out.println("File doesn't exist.\n");
                socket.close();
            }
            else if (!(data.contains("filename"))){
                File file = new File(fName);

                //if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if(!file.exists()){
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                //true = append file
                FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(fName, true);
                data = data.trim();
                byte[] write = data.getBytes();
                fileOuputStream.write(write);
                fileOuputStream.close();

                // sending acknowledgments formatted as ACKn where n is the packet received
                outBuffer = new byte[1024];
                outBuffer = ("ACK" + receivedNo + "").getBytes();
                outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length, source_address, source_port);
                socket.send(outPacket);
                receivedNo++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

client sends the file to the server

public class Client {

```
private DatagramSocket socket = null;
private DatagramPacket inPacket;
private DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
private byte[] inBuffer, outBuffer;
private final int port = 50000;
private int packetNo = 1;

public Client(){
    ChooseFile cf = new ChooseFile();
    String fName = cf.BrowseFilesView();
    this.sendFile(fName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Client();
}

public void sendFile(String fName){

    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.15");
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        Path path = Paths.get(fName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        outBuffer = new byte[1024];
        System.out.println(fName);
        String[] tag = fName.split("\\\\");
        System.out.println(tag[tag.length-1]);
        outBuffer = ("filename"+tag[tag.length-1]).getBytes();
        outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length, address, port);
        socket.send(outPacket);

        String s = null;
        int i = 0;
        int orig = 0;
        while(i < data.length){
            i = orig;
            byte[] send = new byte[1024];
            for( int ii = 0; ii < 1024 && i < data.length; ii++, i++){
                send[ii] = data[i];
            }
            outBuffer = new byte[1024];
            outBuffer = send;
            outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length, address, port);
            socket.send(outPacket);

            inBuffer = new byte[1024];
            inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length);
            socket.receive(inPacket);

            String ack = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());
            int ackNo = 0;

            try{
                ackNo = Integer.parseInt(ack.substring(3));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (packetNo == ackNo){
                System.out.println(packetNo + " " + ackNo);
                orig = i;
                packetNo++;
            }
        }
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In UDP a packet can get corrupted. Since image files are relatively bigger than text files you are able to see this corruption.

Comment: We are using udp not tcp because it is required by teacher :) we need to be able to send any kind of file through udp :) pls help :) we are only able to send text files as of now.

Comment: OK, can you confirm that all packets are received ? and in the correct order ? I think the order will be correct because you wait for an ACK before sending out a new packet. Plus since you are in a local network (judging by 192.) I really don’t see a reason for UDP packet corruption so easily. But then again, lets try a couple of things. First of all reduce your packet size to 512 bytes :)